# Open Fancybox (or equiv) from Form input type="submit"

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, fancybox

is there a way to get a fancybox (http://fancy.klade.lv/) or any
other lightbox from submitting a FORM (with an image button)?

HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="/ACTION/FastFindObj" method="post">
  <input name="fastfind" class="fastfind" value="3463" type="text">
  <input name="weiter" type="submit">
</form>
```

These won't do:

```
    $("form").fancybox();
    $("input").fancybox();
    $("input[name='weiter']").fancybox();
```

Anyone spotting my mistake or having a workaround or an alternative
script? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe all the other answers miss the point of the question (unless I am the one misunderstanding).  What I think the author wanted was to have it such that when a form is submitted, its results are displayed in a fancybox.  I didn't find that any of the other answers provided that functionality.

To achieve this, I used the jQuery Form Plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to easily convert the form to an ajax call.  Then I used the success callback to load the response into a fancybox using a manual call to $.fancybox().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").ajaxForm({
        success: function(responseText){
            $.fancybox({
                'content' : responseText
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

So instead of attaching fancybox to some artificial <a> tag, you attach ajaxForm to the form itself.

Comment: i think at last we may have an answer. the project is now long gone, but this certainly seems like the kind of approach i wanted to go with, i didn't know that plugin existed, thanks Garland!

Comment: Excellent! I hope this helps the next guy trying to do the same thing. It would be nice to see FancyBox include this functionality, but this solution will work well in the meantime.

Comment: Well, it did help the next gal.  Thanks for this, it's just what I was looking for!

Comment: That's exactly what I was loking for, thank you! They should post this usage example on their homepage.

Comment: absolutely brilliant!! Thank you - you really helped me with my university project!

Comment: it does open a fancbox but no contenets insde for me , i am tryinh to load hoghcharts on submit

Comment: This helped me a lot, but I had some configuration attached to my 1st fancybox, and you don't attach it this way... But the issue is easy to fix!
`var localFbOptions = {};
jQuery.extend(
    localFbOptions,
    fancyboxOptions,
    {content': data}
);
    jQuery.fancybox(localFbOptions);`

Answer (score 9):

A better idea is to use on-the-fly html, ie.

```
$("#buttontoclick").click(function() {
    $('<a href="path/to/whatever">Friendly description</a>').fancybox({
        overlayShow: true
    }).click();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

TRY THIS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").fancybox();
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#link").trigger('click');
  });
});

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Button" />
<div style="display:none;"> 
 <a href="#test" id="link">Click</a>
</div>

<div id="test" style="display:none;">fancy box content</div>
```

on click of the button you trigger a click on the href which is hidden.

hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

Fancybox is able deal with ajax requests directly without the need of extra jQuery scripts.

```
$("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url         : "/login.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

<form action="/login.php" method="POST" id="login_form">
<input type="input" size="20" name="username" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, Ian, that's basically the same solution I proposed.  I just used the Form plugin which makes the code shorter and easier to read.

Comment: I like this better, since it doesn't need a plugin which currently hasn't been maintained for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Based from

- Garland Pope's original solution [less .ajaxForm]
- AJAX call solution by Paolo Bergantino [as replacement to .ajaxForm]
- Fancybox loading animation handler by Myself [so the user knows the content is loading]

--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $.fancybox.showLoading(); // start fancybox loading animation
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $.fancybox({ 'content' : response }); // target response to fancybox
            },
            complete: function() { // on complete...
                $.fancybox.hideLoading(); //stop fancybox loading animation
            }
        });
        return false; // stop default submit event propagation
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a ajax submit of the form data, store the data in the session and then trigger the link click.

Comment: No need to store it in the session, you can serialize the form and send that right along the ajax request using jQuery's .serializeArray().

Answer (score 0):

i have just been struggling with this and have found a way to display the results in the iframe of fancy box, i am not good with ajax yet so needed a php solution using jquery any ways here goes, my first answer!!:

a little tweaking will need to be done in your jquery.fancybox js file, i was using `jquery.fancybox.1.3.4.pack.js`. open this up with any editor etc., and search for: `name="fancybox-frame` : thats it, there should only be one instance of this found and will look like:

```
 name="fancybox-frame'+(new Date).getTime()+'"
```

Now you want to rename the whole:

```
fancybox-frame'+(new Date).getTime()+'`
```

to anything your want, i just called it: `"fbframe"` and save the file. Now add the jquery settings, and form as follows and it should work fine:

```
//activate jquery on page load and set onComplete the most important part of this working

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#a").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '100%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'type'              : 'iframe',
                'onComplete':function (){$('#formid').submit();},
            }); 
         });

//function called onclick of form button.      
function activatefancybox(Who){
    $("#setID").val(Who); // i set the value of a hidden input on the form
    $("#a").trigger('click');//trigger the hidden fancybox link

    }

// hidden link 
 <a id="a" href='#'></a> 

 // form to submit to iframe to display results. 
 // it is important to set the target of the form to the name of 
 // the iframe you renamed in the fancybox js file.
 <form name='iduser' id='iduser' action='page.php' target='fbframe' method='post'>
 <input />
 <input />
 <input id='setID' type='hidden' name='userid' value='' />
 <input type="button" onClick='testfb(123)' />
 </form>
```

The proccess is:

> click submit -> call function -> function click FB link -> onComplete

onComplete Submits form to the iframe after FB has loaded it! done.

> Please note I have ripped this out of my current project and have just edited certain required parts, I am still an amateur coder and would reccomend the ajax if you can. and also am only using FB1! FB2 is now available.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may serve your purpose:

- no ajax calls
- use fancybox's **iframe type** option
- pass url [+ data, via jquery's *serialize* method] in fancybox's **href** option
- loading animation is automatic

--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#yourform').submit(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr("action") + "?" + $(this).serialize();
            $.fancybox({
                href: url,
                'type': 'iframe'
            });
            return false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I just had to do this.  Here's how I went about it.

```
$('#elementid').fancybox({
   onStart : function() {
      $.post($(this).attr('href'), $('#formid').serialize());
   }
});
```

That way you can submit the form and call the fancybox all in one shot.  It does submit the form ajax style.  The "submit" button needs to be in an <a> tag.

Hope that helps.