# Integrate html form with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, cgi

I have a HTML form which submits the data to a cgi-bin script which in turns provides some output.

I have seen [this example](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery) that show a modal box with jQuery. This would be perfect for showing the output of the cgi-bin! The problem is that this example works with a
`<a href>` and I can't replace the submit button with a link. How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#your-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // make sure form is NOT submitted by the browser as this would make us navigate away from the current page and therefor render our modal window useless
    $this = $(this); // cache $(this) for better performance
    $.post( // submit the form via POST ...
        $this.attr('action'), // ... to the action URL of our form
        $this.serialize(), // ... with all the form fields as data
        function(data) { // ... and with the server response ...
            $(data).appendTo('body').paulund_modal_box().click(); // ... open the modal.
            // note that the click() is only required for the rather quirky "plugin" that you linked to. I suggest using easybox or the like
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I've tried to replace "$(document).ready(function(){$('.paulund_modal').paulund_modal_box();});" with your code, and I've replaced "your-form" with my form class; yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you replaced the "#" before your-form with an "." then?

Comment: I now have this "$('.feedbackform').submit(function(e){"; the cgi-bin script is executed but I see no modal box and no output (I see the page as nothing has happened).

Comment: See the update … `.appendTo('body')` should do the trick, I guess that "plugin" needs the content to be in the DOM or something.

Comment: Nope, it is like no click is performed (however, I see that the cgi-bin is actually run). Btw, here is my cgi-bin: echo "Content-Type: text/html" echo <body>Parameter modified.</body>

Comment: This worked for me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969522/open-fancybox-or-equiv-from-form-input-type-submit