# Alternatives on how to close Fancybox pop-up window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Fancybox (or equiv) from Form input type=“submit”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969522/open-fancybox-or-equiv-from-form-input-type-submit)

On main page If I click this URL:

```
<a class='EditPop' href='userDel.php?branchid=$branch[id]' style='color: #961017; font-weight: bold;'>Remove</a>
```

A fancybox POP-UP opens and it ask if you're sure if you want to remove the "user", if you press yes, it normally closes pop-up and removes user, but if you press NO, it doesn't close the pop-up box. HOW can I make it work, please assist.

Bellow is my code:

```
<?php
require '../dbconnect.php';

$branchId=$_REQUEST['branchid'];
?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jscript/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var bid = "<?= $branchId ?>";
        $("#BranchDeleteYes").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "userDelete.php",
                data: "BranchId="+bid,
                success: function(html){
                    $('#row'+bid).remove();
                    //alert(html);
                    //$("#content_padded").html(html);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                    }
                });
        });
        $("#BranchDeleteNo").click(function() {
                $("#fancybox-close").click();
        });
    });
    </script>

<div id="BranchDiv" class="addbranchbox">
<center>
    <b>Are you sure you want to delete this Branch?</b>
    <br /><br />
    <input id="BranchDeleteYes" type="button" value="Yes!" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="BranchDeleteNo" type="button" value="No!" />
</center>
</div>
```

And the main question is, is there any alternative to CLOSE fancybox pop-up, since i've tryed almoast everything from simple `fancybox.close();` to hidding it with CSS, but it's just not working properly. The bust would be to have it close "normally" as it does with clicking top right icon (cross icon) OR pressing escape.